# How to switch properly between UIViews or UIViewController inside NSObject Class when clicked the item in tableView inside of NSObject in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, nsobject

What i want is, I have NSObject MenuView which has tableView in it, when i click one the of cells it should remove the current UIViewController or UIView on another controller. I have used shared instance of my MainPageController in NSObject didSelectItem method to replace the current view on MainPageController with the new one by using view.willRemoveSubviews(myCurrentView) and addSubView(newView) but it does nothing even not a crash or error. is there anyone could help me with that please? I am stuck on it for a long time...

here is the info of how i did it.

`inside of NSObject class's didSelectItem` method

```
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    MainPageController.shared.addCustomSubView(View: view)
```

and here how i defined it `in MainPageController`

```
 func addCustomSubView(View: UIView) {
    view.willRemoveSubview(inOutView)
    view.addSubview(View)
    View.anchor(top: headerLine.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: footerLine.topAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(), size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
}
```

`inOutView` also the view of my another controller, which i added as a subView of current `MainPageController`

So i want to replace the `inOutView` with my new `View` coming from the `NSObject` class inside didSelectItem

Comment: Did you used a delegate method to call the function to remove view?

Comment: no, i am just using shared singleton of MainPageControoler and calling the methd inside of it from NSObject class

Answer (score 0):

in `MainPageController`:

```
@objc fileprivate func handleMenuButton() {
    menuLauncher.showSettings()
    menuLauncher.mainPageController = self
}

func showController() {
    let dummyController = UIViewController()
    dummyController.view.backgroundColor = .red
    addChild(dummyController)
    view.addSubview(dummyController.view)
    dummyController.view.anchor(top: headerLine.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: footerLine.topAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(), size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    dummyController.didMove(toParent: self)

}
```

and declare `var mainPageController: MainPageController` in NSObject class and inside of `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` this code:

```
 self.mainPageController?.showController()
```

by doing this I achieved switching between uiviews that is inside of viewController by using NSObject.